# How to resolve fs.existsSync is not a function

Tags: node.js, webpack

In NodeJS I have:

```
const fs = require('fs');
if (!fs.existsSync("some_path")) {
...
}
```

But I get the error:

> TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function

After doing some searching, I read that `Webpack` brings its own `require` which clobbers `node.js`'s `require`, so when you require a `node.js` core module that `webpack` can't resolve to one of your files or dependencies, it throws.

(My stack trace includes `__webpack_require__`)

But how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you writing code intended to run in the browser? If so, how do you expect it to look through the file system?

Comment: @MarkMeyer no, it's NodeJS so it's going to be a server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can allow webpack to use the Node's `require` and include `fs` etc. by targeting node in the config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'backend.js'
  }
}
```

As described here: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/ and https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/

Comment: This is your webpack config file: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/ (add `webpack.config.js` in the root folder).

Comment: I'm using a template created using `create-react-app` (i think) so right now i have 3 `webpack.config.js` files:
`...node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js`
`...node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js`
`...node_modules/raphael/webpack.config.dev.js`

Do i need to use one of them or create a new one?

Comment: @Gambit2007 Not sure about configuring `react`, sorry.

Answer (score 28):

I was facing the same Error like **TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function**

[image]

So, I figured out that one extra line was added automatically which was creating this issue in import.

[image]

after removing this line from import

```
import { TRUE } from "node-sass";
```

the issue has been resolved.

Comment: This helped me, thanks! My editor (Visual Studio Code) somehow magically inserted `import { render } from 'node-sass';` at the top of my file. -.-

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error that you have. Your vscode might have added a new module to your js file. Remove that module and your app should work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

I was working on an electron application, I wanted to send a message from node and get in on the react side, but I was having that same issue when requiring ipcRenderer from electron, I tried
 `import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron';`
and
 `const { ipceRenderer } = require('electron')` This leads to an error due to webpack transforming node's require to its own webpack_require. See more info [here](https://coderedirect.com/questions/241176/electron-angular-fs-existssync-is-not-a-function)

What worked for me was to use

`const {ipcRenderer} = window.require('electron');` on the react side/renderer side from electron

Comment: ['TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function' ReactJS and Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59477396/typeerror-fs-existssync-is-not-a-function-reactjs-and-electron) is probably a better thread for Electron problems.

Comment: get error: `Server Error
ReferenceError: window is not defined` when use `window.require`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I forgot that I'd only imported the promises API, `const fs = require("fs").promises`, which doesn't have `exist` or `existsSync` functions in Node 17.4.0.

To use `exist` or `existsSync`, make sure you've imported `fs` using the sync API (`const fs = require("fs")`).

<sub>*Note: I'm adding this answer as a possible solution for future visitors to a canonical thread for the error, not OP who appears to have required `fs` correctly.*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

It is nothing to worry about, check your code for something like `import { types } from "node-sass";`, it would have mistakenly and automatically imported without you know. Remove that line, and everything should work perfectly.

> Even if it is not `type`, it is something from `node-sass` in your `node_modules` file, and you can't edit that file.
> So look for and remove `import { types } from "node-sass"`

Answer (score 0):

In my case VSCode added a arbitrary import from electron. After removing it my application worked.

```
import { Menu } from 'electron';
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, i needed to send a message from the node to react. I tried importing ipcRenderer from 'electron'; and const ipceRenderer = require('electron') This results in an error owing to webpack changing the node's require to its own webpack require. See more info [here](https://fullstackuser.com/qs/241176/electron-angular-fs-existssync-is-not-a-function)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).