# 'TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function' ReactJS and Electron

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, jsx

I'm having an issue where I'm getting a `TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function` error when my React App loads.

I'm trying to add functionality to my custom MacOS buttons, however, when I seem to `import {remote} from 'electron'`, I get that error.

This is the component source code: https://sourceb.in/1ffad505cd.jsx
This is the error generated in the console: https://sourceb.in/8c01058284.txt

It looks to be an Electron issue but I can't seem to figure out why.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: i resolved this error, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67732925/11764384) is the link

Answer (score 9):

**I was facing the same problem and I've spend half of my day looking for the solution** Instead of importing or requiring electron in the **App.js** as

```
import * as electron from 'electron'
```

**OR**

```
const electron = require("electron")
```

**Go ahead and import electron in your *App.js* as follows using the window object**

```
const electron = window.require("electron")
```

Answer (score 4):

I was found this issue : https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7300

Can you change electron import like this:

const electron = window.require('electron')
and use : electron.remote

Comment: Its saying ```TypeError: window.require is not a function```

Comment: Create window like this

`mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true
  }
})`

Comment: Did you add webPreferences with nodeIntegration when your BrowserWindow is being created?

Comment: Must I have missed that part. So it's now working but I am having issues changing back from fullscreen mode to maximized mode.

Any ideas?

```macButtonsMaximise = () => {
const currentWindow = electron.remote.getCurrentWindow()
if (currentWindow.isMaximized) {
currentWindow.setFullScreen(true)
} else {
currentWindow.setFullScreen(false)
}
}```

Comment: Can yo tell me , what did you see for currentWindow on console when  you change back from fullscreen mode to maximized mode.

Comment: Note, that set-in preference nodeIntegration to true (as mentioned @tpikachu) is against the electron's security guide. https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content

Comment: I did exactly same as above still getting Uncaught TypeError: window.require is not a function