# How to add a menu in Electron+React?

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm trying to add a menu to my Electron+React project, but all of the documentation/tutorials seem incomplete. For example, [the official docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/menu) describe adding a menu from a template in `electron.js`, but don't say how to actually connect that to any behavior in your app. In particular, I need undo/redo to modify the application's state. If you follow that tutorial, you get a menu with a bunch of options that don't do anything.

If I try to create a menu within my application code, I get errors about the `fs` module. Even just trying to `import { Menu } from 'electron'` gives me:

```
TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function
```

Googling that error gives me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53841364/how-to-resolve-fs-existssync-is-not-a-function) SO thread with a solution involving webpack, but I'm not using webpack.

What do I do?

Comment: Add the ```nodeIntegration:true``` when you are creating ```BrowserWindow```

Comment: Where are you going to add menu from? render or main?