# Using Tau-Prolog with React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, prolog, ffi, tau-prolog

I am trying to use Tau-Prolog with Node.js and React.

At the step:

```
session.consult(program);
```

I get this error message:

```
TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function
```

Here is the code to reproduce on the problem:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// These alternatives makes no difference:
var pl = require('tau-prolog');
// var pl = require('./tau-prolog/modules/core.js');
// var pl = require('./tau-prolog.js');

class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        let program = 'fruit(apple). fruit(banana).';
        let session = pl.create();
        // Until here, it's ok. I get Session {rules: {…}, src_predicates: {…},

        // The trouble is at this step:
        session.consult(program);
        ////////
        //////// TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function
        ////////
    }
    
    render() {
        return <div>Hello world</div>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do more research before asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53841364/how-to-resolve-fs-existssync-is-not-a-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve fs.existsSync is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53841364/how-to-resolve-fs-existssync-is-not-a-function)

Comment: JavaScript is one of the worst things of IT.

Comment: @Abdollah: Your edits are no improvement whatsoever.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: I find Javascript one of the best... when I look at it as the 'battle proven  survivor' to Microsoft world domination...

Comment: This is a bug in tau-prolog in the way it detects the node/browser environment.  Looks like it should be fixed in github shortly.  (9 April 2020).

Answer (score 2):

You don't require it on server side, except if you want to evaluate the prolog program on server side and request the result.

If you just want to use it with react in the frontend, you can simply load it like any other frontend library by adding it to your html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tau-prolog.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tau-prolog/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tau-prolog/lists.js"></script>
```

and then either fetch an external .pl file which contains the Prolog code, or use it inline like in [the examples](http://tau-prolog.org/documentation#examples) or in react.