# fs.existsSync is not a function when used in electron

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, fs

I am using `Angular 10`, `Electron 10.0` and `electron-builder v22.8.0`.

When starting my Electron app,  I receive the following error in the console:

```
fs.existsSync is not a function when used in electron
    getElectronPath @ ./node_modules/events/events.js:6
    <anonymous> @ ./node_modules/events/events.js:17
    ./node_modules/electron/index.js @ ./node_modules/events/events.js:19
    __webpack_require__ @ ./webpack/bootstrap:79
    ./src/app/projectview/new/new.component.ts @ ./src/app/projectview/new/new.component.ts:1
    [...]
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap: 79)
```

The error pops up here:

[image]

It happens when I import electron and have the following line in my **renderer process**:

```js
import { remote } from 'electron';

// later on in my component:
remote.dialog.showOpenDialog(...);
```

`nodeIntegration` is `true` when creating the `BrowserWindow`.

```
   [...]
   win = new BrowserWindow({
      webPreferences: {
          webSecurity: false,
          nodeIntegrationInWorker: true,
          nodeIntegration: true,
          allowRunningInsecureContent: (serve) ? true : false,
    },
```

I have browsed entire StackOverflow, but can't find any solution I haven't tried. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you verify that the target in your `webpack.config` is `electron-renderer`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve fs.existsSync is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53841364/how-to-resolve-fs-existssync-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @JakeHolzinger It then compiles but fails with `Cannot read property 'dialog' of undefined`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

so based on your sentence:
`It happens when I import electron and have the following line in my renderer process: import { remote } from 'electron';`

in electron 10 is a breaking change of the remote api.
the webpreference "enableRemoteModule" is now by default false.

activate the module and test again:

```
const w = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        enableRemoteModule: true
    }
})
```

[here you find all breaking changes](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/breaking-changes#default-changed-enableremotemodule-defaults-to-false)

checkout the recommended way to use ipcRenderer:
[use ipcRenderer and not remote](https://medium.com/@nornagon/electrons-remote-module-considered-harmful-70d69500f31)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to remove the arbitrary import from VSCode.

```
import { Menu } from 'electron';
```