# Electron Remote (Close, Minimize etc) not work (Cannot read property 'getCurrentWindow' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I am trying to add close and minimize button on frameless window in Electron JS app. But its not working in anyhow. It's alwasy show "Cannot read property 'getCurrentWindow' of undefined" error. Here is my code:

```
const {remote} = require('electron');

document.getElementById('minimize').onclick = function() {
    var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.minimize();
}

document.getElementById('close').onclick = function() {
    var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.close();
}
```

I also add webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: true} in main.js.

```
win = new BrowserWindow({width: 990, height: 660, title: "Okkhor52 Tools", show: false, resizable: false, frame: false, webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: true}});
```

Please give me a sollution, I try to found this problem sollution in many place but i didn't get exact sollution.

Comment: which electron version are you using? if 10, you find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63269563/fs-existssync-is-not-a-function-when-used-in-electron/63390011#63390011

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sollution is very easy. Just add `webPreferences: {enableRemoteModule: true}` in your BrowserWindow in main.js.

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 990, 
    height: 660,
    title: "Okkhor52 Tools", 
    resizable: false, 
    frame: false, 
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true, 
        enableRemoteModule: true
    }
});
```

Beside `enableRemoteModule: true` you will need to add `nodeIntegration: true` in webPreference, otherwise if you call electron from other's javascript (Like this `const {remote} = require('electron');` ) it will be not work.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have `enableRemoteModule` set to true and are still having this problem, it could very well be that you are requiring [the remote module](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/remote), or requiring a file that requires it ***inside*** the main process, at least this was the case for me. The remote module is not necessary inside the main process and is only for the renderer process.

If you require or require another javascript file that uses `require("electron").remote.getCurrentWindow()` inside the main process then you will get this error.

Solve this simply by not including that code in any way inside the main process.

Comment: I have a file that handles my ipcMain.on calls. I require that file in the main.js file. I am guessing that could be the reason why I am having this error. However, I need to access the mainWindow outside the main.js file, which is the reason why I am trying to access remote.

I am fairly new to electron. Can you help?

Comment: @DavidEssien I am fairly new to electron as well, but I'll see if I can help. Accessing the `mainWindow` outside `main.js` should not be a problem as long as you use `remote`. However, requiring a file that requires `ipcMain` inside your `main.js` (which *will* use `remote` as it is not the main file) will cause the error. Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no way to solve this except by handling your `ipcMain.on` calls inside your `main.js` file (sorry for the late response).

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://nornagon.medium.com/electrons-remote-module-considered-harmful-70d69500f31) article we shouldn't use "remote" at all. The better way is to communicate with the renderer through [Sending Messages](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main/#sending-messages).

First of all, you'll need **WindowNodeHandlers** class to invoke BrowserWindow maximize/unmaximize actions and update isMaximized flag:

```
class WindowNodeHandlers {
  ipcMain.on('maximize', () => {
    BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()?.maximize();
  });

  ipcMain.on('unmaximize', () => {
    BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()?.unmaximize();
  });

  ipcMain.on('isMaximized', (event) => {
    event.returnValue = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()?.isMaximized();
  });
}
```

Then create **ElectronWindowApi** class to communicate between renderer and main processes:

```
class ElectronWindowApi implements MainWindowApi {
  maximize(): void {
   ipcRenderer.send('maximize');
  }

  unmaximize(): void {
   ipcRenderer.send('unmaximize');
  }

  isMaximized(): boolean {
   return ipcRenderer.sendSync('isMaximized') as boolean;
  }
 }
```

After that in your createWindow function create **WindowNodeHandlers** instance and add listeners for these events which will send messages back to renderer process:

```
const createWindow = async () => {
 ...
 new WindowNodeHandlers();

 mainWindow.on('maximize', () =>
   mainWindow?.webContents.send('window-maximized')
 );

 mainWindow.on('unmaximize', () =>
   mainWindow?.webContents.send('window-unmaximized')
 );
}
```

And the last thing you should do - it's to add handlers for these messages and use ElectronWindowApi to call maximize/unmaximize actions on the renderer side:

```
...
const windowApi = new ElectronWindowApi();
const [isMaximized, setIsMaximized] = useState(windowApi.isMaximized());
const onMaximized = () => setIsMaximized(true);
const onRestore = () => setIsMaximized(false);

const toggleMaximize = () => {
  isMaximized ? windowApi.unmaximize() : windowApi.maximize();
};

useEffect(() => {
  ipcRenderer.on('window-maximized', onMaximized);
  ipcRenderer.on('window-unmaximized', onRestore);
}, []);

return (
   <IconButton
      aria-label={isMaximized ? 'minimize' : 'maximize'}
      onClick={toggleMaximize}
    >
      {isMaximized ? (
        <SvgIcon
          component={MinimizeWindowIcon}
        />
      ) : (
        <SvgIcon
          component={MaximizeWindowIcon}
        />
      )}
    </IconButton>
)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, from a safety perspective,I suggest that you should use :

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
width: 990, 
height: 660,
title: "Okkhor52 Tools", 
resizable: false, 
frame: false, 
webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: false, //default 
    enableRemoteModule: true,
    preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
}
```

});
And put you js code into 'preload.js'.

According to the official doc [Disable the Node.js integration in all renderers that display remote content](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content), nodeIntergration: true is very dangerous.

Comment: Having `enableRemoteModule` circumvents a huge amount of the protections of `nodeIntegration: false`